# jquery not supporting firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox

I'm developing a reservation system. The calendar used to pick the date works fine in chrome. But not in firefox. Insdtead it just displays as an ordinary text box. Am I missing any jQuery to be included? Is there any better way of doing this?

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.5.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() 
{
    $('#ClickEventList li').click(function() { 
        $("#ccc").insertAtCaret($(this).text());
        return false
    });
    $('#ClickWordList li').click(function() { 
        $("#bbb").insertAtCaret($(this).text());
        return false
    });
    $("#DragWordList li").draggable({helper: 'clone'});
    $(".txtDropTarget").droppable({
        accept: "#DragWordList li",
        drop: function(ev, ui) {
            $(this).insertAtCaret(ui.draggable.text());
        }
    });
});

$.fn.insertAtCaret = function (myValue) {
    return this.each(function(){
        //IE support
        if (document.selection) {
            this.focus();
            sel = document.selection.createRange();
            sel.text = myValue;
            this.focus();
        }
        //MOZILLA / NETSCAPE support
        else if (this.selectionStart || this.selectionStart == '0') {
            var startPos = this.selectionStart;
            var endPos = this.selectionEnd;
            var scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
            this.value = this.value.substring(0, startPos)+ myValue+ this.value.substring(endPos,this.value.length);
            this.focus();
            this.selectionStart = startPos + myValue.length;
            this.selectionEnd = startPos + myValue.length;
            this.scrollTop = scrollTop;
        } else {
            this.value += myValue;
            this.focus();
        }
    });
};
 </script>
```

Do you know why is this?

Comment: I don't see a calendar in your code.

Comment: Why are you using such an ancient version of jQuery?

Comment: Okay then which version of jquery do you think I should use @Barmar?

Comment: I would also recommend a newer version of jQuery and jQuery UI the latest stable is 1.11 and jQuery UI has the same Version number. The Problem here, i think,  is that Firefox does not support input type=date, and the newer jQueryUI Versions already have a shim for that.

Comment: @Lacrioque I used jquery 1.11.3 and jquery ui 1.11.4 But doesn't seem to produce results in firefox